# Spectral mapping theorem in a subset

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator (specifically it is allowed to be unbounded) and let $f$ be a bounded Borel-measurable function. Through the functional calculus we may make sense of $f(A)$.

Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection, which does *not* commute with $A$. But $PAP$ is of course also self-adjoint.

Is there any relationship between $\sigma(P f(A)P)$ and $\sigma(P A P)$? In particular any relation of inclusion? We may also consider the problem as the relation between $\sigma(\left.A \right|_{W})$ and $\sigma(\left.f(A) \right|_{W})$ where $W$ is the closed subspace which is the range of $P$.

Comment: Wouldn't $f(A)|_W$ be the same as $f(A|_W)$? Hmm or maybe you can only conclude that with the continuous functional calculus.

Comment: How do you know that $PAP$ is a densely-defined self-adjoint operator?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I guess we should assume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to ask about a relationship between $\sigma\big (Pf(A)P\big )$ and $f\big (\sigma(PAP)\big )$?

In any case, there is very little one can say regarding the relationship between these sets.  Consider,  for instance, the following two examples:

1. Let $ f(x)=x^2$, and
   $$
     P=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0},\quad\text{and} \quad A=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0}.
     $$
   Then
   $\sigma\big (Pf(A)P\big )=\{0, 1\}$ and $\sigma(PAP)=\{0\}$, whence $f\big (\sigma(PAP)\big ) = \{0\}$.
2. Let $ f(x)=x^2$, and
   $$
     P=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0},\quad\text{and} \quad A=\pmatrix{1 & 2 \cr 2 & 1}.
     $$
   Then
   $\sigma\big (Pf(A)P\big )=\{0, 5\}$ and $\sigma(PAP)=\{0, 1\}$, whence $f\big (\sigma(PAP)\big ) = \{0, 1\}$.

I suspect the only thing one can  say for sure is that both
$\sigma\big (Pf(A)P\big )$ and $\sigma(PAP)$ contain zero!

---

**EDIT**.  Here is a more radical example showing that,  for any two compact  subsets $E$ and $F$ of $\mathbb R$, both
containing zero, one can find a bounded operator $A$, and a function $f$, such that
$$
  f\big (\sigma(PAP)\big )=E, \quad \text{and}\quad \sigma\big (Pf(A)P\big )=F.
  $$

Let $x$ and $y$ be any two  bounded,  self-adjoint operators on $H$,  and put
$$
  z=y-x^3-2x.
  $$
Consider the operator $A$ on $H\oplus H$ given by
$$
  A=\pmatrix {x & 1\cr 1 & z}.
  $$
With $f(t)=t^3$, one then has that
$$
  f(A)=  A^3=\pmatrix {x^3+2x+z & x^2+z^2+xz+1 \cr x^2+z^2+zx+1  & z^3+2z+x}.
  $$
Letting $P=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0}$,  it follows that
$$
  Pf(A)P=\pmatrix {x^3+2x+z & 0 \cr 0 & 0} = \pmatrix {y& 0 \cr 0 & 0}.
  $$
Recalling that we were given closed sets $E$ and $F$ above, choose $x$ and $y$ such that
$\sigma (x) = \root 3 \of E$, and
$\sigma (y)=F$.  So,
$$
  \sigma (PAP)= \sigma \pmatrix {x & 0 \cr 0 & 0} = \sigma (x)\cup \{0\} = \root 3 \of E \cup \{0\} = \root 3 \of E,
  $$
whence
$$
  f\big (\sigma (PAP)\big ) =  f\big (\root 3 \of E \big ) = E,
  $$
while
$$
  \sigma \big (Pf(A)P\big )= \sigma (y)\cup \{0\} = F,
  $$